# WPF insert content property within control template that include thumb make an error

Tags: wpf

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Use Thumb" TargetType="Button">
        <Button>
            <Thumb DragDelta="onDragDelta">
            </Thumb>
        </Button>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

I tried to make a button resizable and I reached the solution with this code.

```
<Button x:Name="btnLoadFromFile" Content="File Load" Canvas.Left="44" Canvas.Top="16" 
    Template="{StaticResource Use Thumb}" Height="20" Width="92"/>
```

But Another problem made with this is that content of button not appeared. I insert property content like **content="some content"** in a button. but error appear with some kind of the content duplication problem.

Comment: The `ControlTemplate` is supposed to include a `<ContentPresenter />` element. What is your question?

Comment: What i want to know is how make button's content appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a new wpf window, add a button.

In the designer, right click it and choose Edit Template> Edit template off the list of options.

You should get something like this added to your window resources:

```
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Start with this.

Be very sure not to remove the part:

```
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
```

Because the content presenter is where your content will appear.

Re-templating wpf controls is tricky stuff. You should start with a copy you obtain like this and make a series of small iterations towards whatever you're trying to achieve. Small change... try it... small change.... try it.
Then when you do something and the content disappears you know you just broke it and you have a far better chance of working out what you did wrong.

As to making a button re-sizable.

This is an advanced task if you wish to make the functionality internal to a button.

Putting a regular button in a column and row with gridsplitters around it might be something to consider.

If you put things in a button then the button is designed to be clicked. You click it and it's command is invoked. The thing to consider is what happens when you click a thumb that's inside a button? And how's it getting out the button once it's in there so you can move it around?

Visual studio has resizing functionality in the designer.
This is handled by putting controls in the adorner layer.

If you set height and width on that button you added and take a look in the designer window.
Use Ctrl+ scroll wheel to zoom right in if necessary.

That button has some little squares round it:

[image]

When you mouse over those the cursor changes.
You can click and drag them to resize from corner or side.

This is another way to achieve your purpose.
You'd need some controls to go in the adorner layer and some dragging on those when they're visible.
You'd also need some sort of a key chord or something to switch the control into re-sizable mode and make those handles visible or hide them after you finished.

You could do worse than to take a look at the source code for this article here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1

This has resizable shapes and you could probably adapt the approach.  Or maybe just see how big a task you're taking on.